# No file matches include / exclude patterns in serverless deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Tyring to deploy my app on dev server. I did add a exclude field earlier to exclude node_modules from the deployment which caused this error. But i've removed that but the error is still here.

Any possible solutions?

**Serverless.yml**

```
service: lambda-woo-user-service-dev-app
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1
  memorySize: 2048
  apiGateway:
    restApiId: pc92cc9jz8
    restApiRootResourceId: 3y783dgut3
  provider.iam.role.statements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::wooo-s3", "/*"]] }
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-plugin-warmup
custom:
  warmup:
    default:
      enabled: true # Whether to warm up functions by default or not
      folderName: ".warmup" # Name of the folder created for the generated warmup
      cleanFolder: false
      memorySize: 256
functions:
  app:
    handler: server.handler
    warmup:
      default:
        enabled: true
    timeout: 120
    events:
      - http:
          path: /
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          # contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
      - http:
          path: /{proxy+}
          method: ANY
          cors: true
          # contentHandling: CONVERT_TO_BINARY
```

Error Screen:

```
$ serverless
DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
         - PORT
         - APP_NAME
         - EMAIL

? Do you want to deploy now? Yes
DOTENV: Loading environment variables from .env:
         - PORT
         - APP_NAME
         - EMAIL
        
Deploying lambda-woo-user-service-dev-app to stage prod (us-east-1)
WarmUp: Creating warmer "default" to warm up 1 function

× Stack lambda-woo-user-service-dev-app-prod failed to deploy (2s)
Environment: win32, node 18.12.1, framework 3.25.1, plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Credentials: Local, environment variables                                                                                                                                      
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
No file matches include / exclude patterns

1 deprecation found: run 'serverless doctor' for more details
```

Cannot excatly find where the issue is, I've removed the exclude stage but still the same error.

Comment: Can you share the logs and the stack trace from Cloudwatch? Overall I think if you provide a bit more context we could try to produce better-informed help with whatever challenge you are encountering.

Comment: It is not getting deployed on AWS. Cannot share the stack trace as it is not deployed, This is all I have as of now.